# How to use recurring CTE for Time Series

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which shows the following data

Called Declines

| date | accountId | declineReason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/10/22 | 1344 | Not enough funds |
| 05/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 05/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |
| 06/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 07/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |
| 07/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 10/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |
| 11/10/22 | 1344 | Incorrect Password |
| 11/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 12/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |
| 13/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 15/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |
| 15/10/22 | 1222 | Incorrect Password |
| 17/10/22 | 1677 | timeout |

etc (note declineReasons may increase in terms of distinct values and is not limited to 3 shown)

what I would like to have as my final table is the below

| WeekEnd | declineReason | CountOfReasonPerWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/10/22 | Not enough funds | 1 |
| 10/10/22 | Incorrect Password | 3 |
| 10/10/22 | timeout | 3 |
| 17/10/22 | Not enough funds | 0 |
| 17/10/22 | Incorrect Password | 4 |
| 17/10/22 | timeout | 3 |

I have created the week loop and table which counts no. of total declines

```
WITH date_loop AS (
            SELECT
                CAST('2022-08-01' AS DATE) AS WeekEnd,   
                CAST('2022-08-02' AS DATE) AS BeforeDate,
                CAST('2022-07-25' AS DATE) AS AfterDate 
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                DATEADD(ww, 1, WeekEnd),
                DATEADD(ww, 1, BeforeDate),
                DATEADD(ww, 1, AfterDate)
            FROM date_loop
            WHERE BeforeDate < DATEADD(ww, -1, GETDATE())
    ),

CountOfDDeclineByReasonAllTime AS (
    SELECT
        count(*) AS totalDeclinesPerReasonCode
    FROM
        Declines
    GROUP BY
        declineReason),
```

But I am unsure how I can use a correlated subquery to get values returned in the format as desired, if anyone has any pointers that would be great

Comment: Its not clear to me how the data in table 1 is transformed into the data in table 2? I feel like you are missing a lot of sample data.

Comment: HI @Dale - I didn't post the whole tables but I will make the sample match by editing the tables - thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Hi RF, thanks for solving this - only thing is on the 0 values, but i don't think that will matter when displaying :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data

```
CREATE TABLE Declines(
   date          VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL
  ,accountId     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,declineReason VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Declines
(date,accountId,declineReason) VALUES
('04/10/22',1344,'Not enough funds'),
('05/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('05/10/22',1677,'timeout'),
('06/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('07/10/22',1677,'timeout'),
('07/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('10/10/22',1677,'timeout'),
('11/10/22',1344,'Incorrect Password'),
('11/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('12/10/22',1677,'timeout'),
('13/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('15/10/22',1677,'timeout'),
('15/10/22',1222,'Incorrect Password'),
('17/10/22',1677,'timeout');
```

query
*first* since your value is not date change to date by using `Convert(date, column, 3)`
*second* get the last day of week  by using
`DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, column)), column)  as WeekEnd`
*third* use `Subquery` to have better understanding of using `Count function`

```
select WeekEnd,
       declineReason,
       Count(declineReason) CountOfReasonPerWeek
from   (select Dateadd(dd, 7 - ( Datepart(dw, Convert(date, date, 3)) ),
                      Convert(date, date, 3)
               ) WeekEnd,
               declineReason
        from   Declines) a
group  by declineReason,
          WeekEnd
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ECIp1ky6)